# Indenting records with space in a T-SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns records based on a `Department ID`:

```
Employee Name                ManagerID         SupervisorID                ID  
    John Smith                  1                     1                      1  
    Tom Jones                   1                     2                      2  
    Robert Thompson             1                     2                      3
    Jennifer Stevens            1                     4                      4
```

I want to indent the records that are returned as follows:

- If ManagerID = ID (no indentation)
- If SupervisorID = ID (2 spaces indented)
- Else (4 spaces indented)*

Something like:

```
John Smith  
   Tom Jones  
       Robert Thompson  
   Jennifer Stevens
```

How would I accomplish that?

Comment: You'd be better of creating a recursive CTE matching on `SupervisorID`, which would then work for arbitrary depths.

Comment: This is something that you should NOT be doing in SQL, this is something the application code should handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
SPACE (
CASE
  WHEN ManagerID = ID THEN 0
  WHEN SupervisorID = ID THEN 2
  ELSE 4
  END
) + [Employee Name] AS [Employee Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

USe a CASE statement?

```
EmployeeName = 
    CASE ManagerID
        WHEN 1 THEN [Employee Name]
        WHEN 2 THEN '  ' + [Employee Name]
        ELSE '    ' + [Employee Name]
    END
```

(Note: Pseudo-code, not tested)

Edit: Removed `CASE` from `END CASE`.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
 (EmployeeID int,
  EmployeeName nvarchar(25),
  ManagerID int)
;

INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES (1, 'John Smith', 1)
;

INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES (2, 'Bill Gates', 2)
;

INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES (3, 'Adam Smith', 2)
;

INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES (4, 'John Gates', 3)
;

INSERT INTO Employee
VALUES (5, 'Jake Smith', 4)
;

SELECT 
  EmployeeName = 
    CASE ManagerID
      WHEN 1 THEN EmployeeName
      WHEN 2 THEN '  ' + EmployeeName
      ELSE '    ' + EmployeeName
    END 
FROM Employee
```

Output:

```
EmployeeName
-----------------------------
John Smith
  Bill Gates
  Adam Smith
    John Gates
    Jake Smith
```

Comment: Hm, ID 2 is Bill Gates, so in order to make any sense Adam Smith should be indented one more, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow for an arbitrary number of levels (e.g. each person just as a boss, and this then can be of any depth), you have to use a recursive CTE. Also, the query may need to be written so that it correctly re-orders depending on the relationship (so that, in your sample data, the row for Robert always appears after Tom and not as first or after any other person).

[Here's a fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2bb8c/1/0) showing how this works; I added some more people to make it more interesting.

```
WITH EmployeeHierarchy AS (
  SELECT
    0 [Level],
    CAST(1 AS float) [Step],
    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.ID) AS float) [Sort],
    e.*
    FROM Employee e
    WHERE e.BossID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    h.[Level]+1,
    h.[Step]/(SUM(1) OVER ()+1),
    h.[Sort]+(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.ID))*(h.[Step]/(SUM(1) OVER ()+1)),
    e.*
    FROM Employee e
    JOIN EmployeeHierarchy h ON (h.ID = e.BossID)
)
SELECT SPACE(h.Level*2)+h.Name [Employee Name], h.BossID, h.ID
  FROM EmployeeHierarchy h
  ORDER BY h.Sort
```

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddler link. REPLICATE() was the function I was looking for. Helped me avoid a lot of unnecessary code.